# Combining detectors and descriptors for feature matching

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, sift

I have used Python OpenCv to match features (keypoints) using SIFT for instance. Here, SIFT has been used as a detector and descriptor.

How can we use Harris corner for instance as a detector, and SIFT as a descriptor. Is there a code example that can show how we can combine some detector with another descriptor?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure about python but in C++ there are 3 functions for sift for example: 1. for detection+description 2: just detection 3: just description..But you might have to add imformation that your alternative detector might not compute like scale/octave and orientation.

Answer (score 0):

All detector/descriptor classes have methods to get the features or descriptors only. But you can't combine all extractors with all descriptors. Descriptors may need some Special Infos provided by the feature detector.

The find-object program (https://introlab.github.io/find-object/) is a nice testbed for testing detector/descriptor pairs.